# Why does my file input only accept one file?

Tags: html, razor, file-upload

I have the following Razor markup with a file input that I want to be able to select multiple files with:

```
<form asp-action="Upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple onchange="javascript: updateFileList();" />
    <br />Selected files:
    <div id="fileList"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
        <a asp-action="Explorer" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Yet each time I select one file, the input's value changed to only that file, i.e. it only lets me select one file at a time.

For the curious, the `updateFileList` function looks like this:

```
function updateFileList() {
    var input = document.getElementById('file');
    var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
    output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
    }
    output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I only tagged this as `Razor` so commentors don't query or whinge about the `asp-action` attributes.

Comment: _"I only tagged this as Razor"_ - the Razor part is irrelevant. Create a pure HTML [mcve]. You can do this using the HTML generated by Razor. Then add the JS, to see if that changes something. Also mention the browsers this happens in.

Comment: @CodeCaster There is nothing at all wrong with using Razor in the question, and if my code is Razor I will not change it just for the question. But I will get some people complaining that `asp-action` is not HTML. Too bad for them if the question is tagged as `Razor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is I was trying to select file after file by clicking the `Choose Files` button once for each file. If I click it only once and select multiple files in the file selection dialogue, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your updateFileList() function
form me its working correctly

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple onchange="javascript: updateFileList();" />
```

Comment: Why the hell did this get a downvote? Upvoted to compensate.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't upvote only to compensate, but because the person who answered made sense. It wasn't just "works for me" but a suggestion as to where the problem may lie. On thinking about it, I agree with you, but I will still upvote, to compensate or not, where I feel like it.